# Call (show) a modal popup located in MasterPage from it's childs

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit, modalpopupextender

I'm trying to make a default modal box that must be accessible from any part of the application, and need to be called whenever I want from inside any page. (must be called from code-behind).

So I came up with the idea of a Panel + modalPopupExtender placed in the MasterPage, and calling it from child pages via code-behind.

How can I do that? Or perhaps you guys have a better idea to solve this.

Comment: Should this behave differently than, say, redirecting to another page and returning once the dialog has been dealt with? Or am I confused and by "code-behind" you mean some JavaScript in your page?

Comment: Just want to show a modal box, that the user can read, then close.
(Code behind = .cs file)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the modal is to be called from the code behind, you can achieve it like this

**Add a method to your Master Page**

```
public class MyMaster : MasterPage
{
     public void ShowModal(string someParameter)
     {
          // Do your logic here
          // Show the modal
     }
}
```

**Then add a method to your page, or page base like this...**

```
public void ShowModal(string someParameter)
{
     MyMaster masterPage = this.Master as MyMaster;
     masterPage.ShowModal(someParameter);
}
```

I recommend using a base class for your pages so that you don't have to replicate the above method.

Comment: This will surely work if i'm using a modalPopupExtender, but what if I want to show some other panel or div, using something like ajax (updatepanels wouldn't work because the triggers aren't in the same page) ?

Comment: That is true.  You can create a user control that leverages shared javascript code to use AJAX to pull content and show them in a popup modal.

Answer (score 1):

Add a method to your Master page. For example:

```
public void ShowMpSignup4free()
{
    mpSignup4free.Show();
}
```

Then call this method from the code behind page like this:

```
protected void lbSignin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MasterPages_WebMasterPage wm = (MasterPages_WebMasterPage)(this.Master);
    wm.ShowMpSignup4free();
}
```

Here mpSignup4free is ID of ModelPopupExtender and MasterPages_WebMasterPage is name of master page (WebMasterPage is name of master page placed in folder MasterPages. That is why the complete name of master page is MasterPages_WebMasterPage).

and lbSignin is Link button on the page whose master page is WebMasterPage  to whose click event will show the model popup.

For avoiding post back place the lbSignin link button in UpdatePanel...